# Files copied to output only on the second run

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

On a NET Core 7 application I need to build Client files and copy them to `/webroot`:

```
<Target Name="Client" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="npm install" />
  <Exec Command="npm run build" />
</Target>
```

This, as expected, runs when I Build or Publish the application.

**Note:** The command `npm run build` deletes the current webroot folder, builds the client files, creates the webroot folder and copy the files to it in this order.

To ensure that `webroot` folder is copied to output directory when publishing the application I added the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="webroot\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

However the folder is copied only the second time I run the command `botnet publish`.

It seems Publish runs before Build ... How to solve this?

**Update**

I was able to solve this by using:

```
  <Target Name="Client Build" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'debug'">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Client Publish" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <ClientFiles Include="webroot\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(ClientFiles->'%(FullPath)')">
        <RelativePath>webroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

But I am not sure if this is the better way. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have two issues.

When MSBuild loads a project it evaluates all `ItemGroup` and `PropertyGroup` elements that are outside of targets and it builds a graph of the `Target` elements. `ItemGroup` and `PropertyGroup` elements that are inside targets are not evaluated until the target is executed.

If the `ItemGroup` you show is outside of any target, then the include of the `webroot\**` files has been evaluated before any targets in the project have been run. On a first run build, the `npm` generated files don't exist yet at the point when the `ItemGroup` is evaluated and can't be included. On a second run, the files left from the prior build are found.

If you want to include files that are generated during the build, you need to move the `ItemGroup` to be inside a target so that the evaluation is delayed until after the files exist.

e.g.

```
  <Target Name="Client">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="webroot\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

In the example I removed the `AfterTargets="Build"` attribute.

The attribute `AfterTargets="Build"` will run this target after everything else in the build -- including the copy of files to the output directory that you are trying to leverage by adding the `CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"` metadata.

If the `npm` command runs don't have any dependence on anything produced in the project to be able to run successfully, you can perform the commands early.

e.g. Run `npm` before everything else:

```
  <Target Name="Client" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
```

If the `npm` commands must be run after the project's `Compile` and before files are copied to the output directory, you will need something like the following:

```
  <Target Name="Client" AfterTargets="AfterCompile" BeforeTargets="GetCopyFilesToOutputDirectoryItems">
```

Comment: I was also able to kind of solve it using another approach ... I just added an update. Your approach seems simpler. Do you think it would be better than what I got? Thank you.